# No stack trace info when error happens in Office JS API

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We're getting lots of Office JS API errors in Application Insights, but they don't have a stack trace. All that we have - `The browser's same-origin policy prevents us from getting the details of this exception. Consider using 'crossorigin' attribute.`. Note, we have set 'crossorigin' attribute to `office.js` in Add-In HTML:

```
<script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The issue is following: office.js injects additional scripts depending on environment and these scripts don't have crossorigin set. For example `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.01.js` or the one which is injected in Outlook for Mac. 
It's really painful not to have access to stack trace and not be able to report these errors to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue.  I've logged this as an issue in the OfficeDev/office-js repo on GitHub, so that the product team can investigate:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/14.

Comment: Is this happening only on Mac or on Windows as well

Comment: Office js is very unstable. :(.  SO many limitations which are not documented, no error logging, debugging very difficult in clients like Windows and Mac..