# Cannot get user identity token via Office JS API

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Our production customers are struggling with the following error:
Office JS API doesn't return user identity token and this blocks the whole usage of our Add-In.

Error which we see in logs:

```json
{
    "name": "AccessRestricted",
    "message": "Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'.",
    "code": 9017
}
```

Sometimes it appears when a laptop wakes up after sleep mode, sometimes not.

Also, the following error appears sometimes (but not every time when `AccessRestricted` error is seen) in Office JS API when our code executes get user identity token async:

```
"Unable to get property 'Execute' of undefined or null reference",
"number": -2146823281,
"stack": 
    "TypeError: Unable to get property 'Execute' of undefined or null reference
     at n.prototype.execute (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1... (truncated by our logging system)
```

Outlook version is 16.0.8528.2147 and add-in was pinned.
P.S. Office JS API was initialized, it's not a root cause of this problem.

Here are the pieces of code:

```js
sfMailApp.OfficeManager.prototype.getCallbackTokenAsync = function () {
    var item = this.getItem();

    return !item.isFake ? this._loadItemAsync(Office.context.mailbox, 'getCallbackTokenAsync') : sfMailApp.utils.resolveDeferred('');
};

sfMailApp.OfficeManager.prototype.getIdentityTokenAsync = function (force) {
    var ls = getLocalStorage();
    var lastUpdateIdentityTokenTimestamp = ls.getItem('identityTokenUpdate');
    var cachedIdentityToken = ls.getItem('identityToken');

    var lastUpdateIdentityTokenDifference = !sfMailApp.utils.isNullOrEmpty(lastUpdateIdentityTokenTimestamp) ? (new Date().getTime() - parseInt(lastUpdateIdentityTokenTimestamp)) : null;

    if (sfMailApp.utils.isNullOrEmpty(cachedIdentityToken) || cachedIdentityToken === 'null' || sfMailApp.utils.isNullOrEmpty(lastUpdateIdentityTokenDifference) || force ||
        (lastUpdateIdentityTokenDifference / (1000 * 60)) > sfMailApp.settings.identityTokenUpdateIntervalMinutes) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        var item = this.getItem();

        if (!item.isFake) {
            sfMailApp.analytics.trackEvent('LoadUserIdentityTokenAsync', 'Start', {
                user: sfMailApp.mailService.userEmail
            });

            this._loadItemAsync(Office.context.mailbox, 'getUserIdentityTokenAsync').done(function (token) {
                ls.setItem('identityTokenUpdate', new Date().getTime());
                ls.setItem('identityToken', token);
                sfMailApp.sessionManager.setIdentityToken(token);
                deferred.resolve(token);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                ls.setItem('identityTokenUpdate', null);
                ls.setItem('identityToken', null);
                sfMailApp.analytics.trackEvent('LoadUserIdentityTokenAsync', 'Fail', {
                    user: sfMailApp.mailService.userEmail,
                    message: err ? JSON.stringify(err) : 'null'
                });
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        } else {
            sfMailApp.analytics.trackEvent('Item', 'Empty', {
                user: sfMailApp.mailService.userEmail,
                message: 'Error while getting identity token - inbox item is empty'
            });
            sfMailApp.sessionManager.setIdentityToken(cachedIdentityToken);
            return sfMailApp.utils.resolveDeferred(cachedIdentityToken);
        }

        return deferred.promise();
    } else {
        sfMailApp.sessionManager.setIdentityToken(cachedIdentityToken);
        return sfMailApp.utils.resolveDeferred(cachedIdentityToken);
    }
};


sfMailApp.OfficeManager.prototype._loadItemAsync = function (obj, name) {

    if (sfMailApp.utils.isCommands() && sfMailApp.isCommandsMagicPixel) {
        return sfMailApp.utils.rejectDeferred({
            message: 'Async Office JS API should not be called in Commands while inserting MagicPixel'
        });
    }

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var maxAttempCount = 5;
    var attempInterval = 1000;
    var attempCount = 0;
    var _this = this;

    function checkResult(asyncResult) {
        var processFunc = function () {
            try {
                if (_this._checkProperyExists(obj, name)) {
                    obj[name](checkResult);
                } else {
                    checkResult(null);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                if (name !== 'loadCustomPropertiesAsync' && name !== 'getCallbackTokenAsync') {
                    sfMailApp.analytics.trackException(e, name + '.Fail', {
                        user: sfMailApp.mailService.userEmail,
                        error: e ? JSON.stringify(e) : null
                    });
                }
                checkResult(null);
            }
        }

        if ((sfMailApp.utils.isNullOrEmpty(asyncResult) || asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) && attempCount < maxAttempCount) {
            attempCount++;
            if (attempCount <= 1) {
                processFunc();
            } else {
                setTimeout(processFunc, attempInterval);
            }
        } else {
            if (asyncResult && asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                deferred.resolve(asyncResult.value);
            } else {
                var params = {
                    user: sfMailApp.mailService.userEmail
                };
                if (asyncResult) {
                    params.status = asyncResult.status;
                    params.value = asyncResult.value;
                    params.error = JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error);
                }

                if (name !== 'loadCustomPropertiesAsync' && name !== 'getCallbackTokenAsync') {
                    sfMailApp.analytics.trackException(new Error(name + '.Fail'), '', params);
                }
                deferred.reject(asyncResult);
            }
        }
    }

    var inboxItem = this.getItem();

    if (obj && !obj.isFake && !inboxItem.isFake) {
        checkResult(null);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve({});
    }

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using that results in this error?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thank you for your prompt response, the code has been attached.

Comment: I'm not seeing where your referencing a method or property called `Execute`. Which line is it failing on?

Comment: @Mark, please check the reference to the URL of the script. It's your Office JS API code https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1...

Comment: I understand, but I'm still not clear which call _into_ Office.js is triggering the error.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur unfortunately, I can't help you with that. Once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294347/no-stack-trace-info-when-error-happens-in-office-js-api is fixed I might provide the detailed info.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur it seems that calling window.reload fixes the issue. So, we added following workaround: reload window when either 9017 error code or AccessRestricted error message was observed. Could you confirm that this workaround could be used?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for letting us know, Sviatoslav. We are aware of the issue and are currently investigating it. We will update this answer once a fix has been identified!

Comment: I assume you're still seeing issues with the useridentitytoken calls. Do you see them for the most recent outlook builds? If so, could you share the recent build number? We have added an extra parameter in the asyncResult object called diagnostic, for token calls, that should provide you with some more information about the failure. This should be available in clients with version > 16.0.10224.10000. Could you take a look at that and see if that helps with some extra information and share here. What exchange version is the client connecting to?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am currently suffering from this error. My version is 16.35 20030802. Have you found a solution yet? Could it be that I am using my school email in outlook, and an admin has restricted certain access to apis?