# Office JS API: ItemChanged event is not fired, current Item has old context

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

If Add-In is pinned in the latest Outlook 2016 (16.0.9226.2114) for ~60 minutes ItemChanged event is not being fired, current Item has old context from some email message which was opened a long time ago. It seems that https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js has been updated which caused the regression.

We see the following errors in the console:
SEC7120: Origin https://staging-addinsf.smartcloudconnect.io not found in Access-Control-Origin header 
main.html
This error could be related to [No stack trace info when error happens in Office JS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294347/no-stack-trace-info-when-error-happens-in-office-js-api)

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.
Main.html

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

Note, when Add-In is re-loaded (mouse right click -> "Reload") the issue is gone and everything works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. A small code snipped with steps to reproduce this would be helpful.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur our add-in is too huge to get a code snippet for you which 100% reproduces the issue. I added the logs from the browser console. Unfortunately, due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294347/no-stack-trace-info-when-error-happens-in-office-js-api I cannot get more details re errors in console.Could you suggest a workaround for the issue?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Marc, we found the STRs: we call window.location.reload in some cases (eg Office JS API throws multiple errors, the customization of our app has been changed, it was updated etc). Previously, window.location.reload() did a good job and everything worked properly. But right now window.location.reload() just breaks ItemChanged event and doesn't let us access even basic properties. Why was that behavior changed? Can we have it back? I think it's okay to let Add-Ins reload themselves on specific actions of the user or on updates from our server. 
Is there valid way to reload it now?

Comment: A couple of potential workarounds would be 1) Forcing a true `reload` by also disregarding cached resources: `window.location.reload(true)` or 2) Avoid potentially re-posting data (`reload` will re-execute whatever action got you there) by navigating to the same location using  `window.location.href = window.location.href`. Note that #2 won't work if you rely on URL fragments (`#` in the URL).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur both doesn't work for me. Anything else?

Comment: Can you try reproducing this issue with a simple add-in? We couldn't reproduce this on our end.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The algorithm is the following: 1) Open any Add-In with the support of Pinning, pin it; 2) Open F12 tools for it 3) Run console command window.location.reload(true). Then ItemChange event won't be fired and Add-In won't change the data on switching Emails. We need to have this working - window.location.reload(true) command must not break ItemChange event from being fired on switching emails.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Any updates?

Comment: @SviatoslavLobach we are able to reproduce this issue in-house and are currently working on a solution. Is there a reason why your add-in sometimes reloads itself with `window.location.reload(true)` ?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT What's the ETA for the fix? We needed to reload the Add-In in some cases when Office JS API just unexpectedly failed and stopped responding. Also, we have internal settings which should be applied (new beta UI version) with the reload of the Add-In.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Kind follow up on ETA for the fix.

Comment: We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.0.10231.10000 or later. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thank you!